# Is it necessary to unsubscribe events which are subscribed in xaml WPF, If so how to unsubscribe the events?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it necessary to unsubscribe events which are subscribed in Xaml WPF??. If so how can I unsubscribe the events?? In the below code I have subscribed the MouseDown and  OnCellClosed Events in Xaml. If its really necessary to unsubscribe the events then how can I achieve this??

```
<DataTemplate  x:Key="Style2">
     <local:MyCellStyle2 MouseDown="MyCellStyle2_MouseDown" OnCellClosed="MyCellStyle2_OnCellClosed"   />
</DataTemplate>
```

Update : 
I am using a listBox with a itemtemplate which is defined above. Each item in the list box will be displayed with the datatemplate "MyCellStyle2". This "MyCellStyle2" control has a close button and when on clicked the object is removed from the listbox's collection but the object's mousedown and OnCellClosed events (see above) are still subscribed and which will not allow the removed item to be garbage collected. How can I overcome this. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In what context should it be necessary?

Comment: Doesn't it creates a memory leak if I don't unsubscribe it??

Comment: No, the dependency is the other way around. The removed object references the collection of event handlers. Thus, the targets (probably your window object) won't be garbage collected as long as the object stays alive. However, the object itself can be collected any time if no other references point to it. The event handlers do not reference the event publisher.

Comment: Key thing to remember is : if the publisher is long lived than the subscriber, then yes, you need to unsubscribe the event. In this case it isn't. Your cellstyle isn't long lived than the class where you have this. So no. No need to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to unsubscribe from those events. When your window is closed everything on and of that window is disposed of, so no unsubscription is needed and no memory leak will occur. If you really want to unsubscribe from one of those events from code-behind, e.g. to turn that event off temporarily, you can do so as described in [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx).

#### Update

As to your `MyCellStyle2` scenario, I still think you don't have to worry about event unsubscription. In the arrangement you describe, your `Window` holds a reference to your `ListBox`, which holds a reference to the item, which in turn holds references to the events exposed by your `Window`, effectively holding references to your `Window`. Note that it's the item that references the events, not the other way round, because when something happens it's the item that should call the corresponding event. So when the item is removed from the `ListBox`, it should be garbage collected because the reference to it is released, even though it's holding references to other objects.

On the other hand, if you do observe that the items are memory leaked after they are removed, maybe there are other reasons. Most likely you're facing the problem described in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938416), [this](http://ozcode-orchard.azurewebsites.net/top-3-memory-leak-inducing-pitfalls-of-wpf-programming), and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micmcd/archive/2008/03/07/avoiding-a-wpf-memory-leak-with-databinding-black-magic.aspx). The cure is to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Hi, you are right when we close the window, everything will be disposed. but what if I don't close the window?? I have updated my question please check. Let me know if u need more info

Answer (score 0):

No need to unsubscribe events those are create in Xaml. You need to unsubscribe events which are created in Code Behind.

eg:

this.MouseDoubleClick += UserControl1_MouseDoubleClick;

this.MouseDoubleClick -= UserControl1_MouseDoubleClick;

Comment: Hi Joby, why there is no need to unsubscribe events which are created in XAML?? Will the Xaml unsubscribe its  event atomatically, if so when and where it unsubscribes??

Comment: I'm sorry. But it is ridiculous to say that you don't need to unsubscribe events in xaml and need to unsubscribe events which you subscribe in code behind. Xaml or code behind is irrelevant here. Refer my comment above for bit more details..